# How can I perform the following Insert action dynamically

Tags: plsql

```
INSERT INTO table_name
        ( A, B, C, D, E ) 
        SELECT
            J,K,L,M,N FROM EMP
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thanks!!,can someone help me with a solution for this one.I need to perform the above mentioned insert action dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming emp has columns J, K, L, M, N I guess you need a procedure something like below:

```
create or replace procedure dyna_insert
(
  pi_emp_no number
)
is
begin
  insert into table_name
  ( A, B, C, D, E) 
  select j,k,l,m,n from emp where emp_no = pi_emp_no;

end;
```